# particular system port avliable checking by using java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sockets: Discover port availability using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java)

hi,

how can i check the particular system port is avliable or not by using java.

Thanks 
Murali

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java

Answer (score 1):

Bind to it, see if you get an exception, release it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code snippet:

int minPortNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int maxPortRange = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

```
    for (int i = minPortNumber; i <= maxPortRange; i++) {
        try {
            Socket ServerSok = new Socket("127.0.0.1", i);

            System.out.println("Port number in use: " + i);

            ServerSok.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Port number not in use: " + i);
        }



    }
```

if the port number is use the socket connection will be opened else it will throw exception.