# Getting an open socket for tcp connection in java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, port

I'm developing a torrent with Java and there is a small question I have. How can I get an open socket for my process in java? I need about 100 free sockets in a sequence, just like 10000-10100. All I know is that by using

```
socket = new Socket(ip, port);
```

We need to provide ip and port. Well of course this is the case of debug and my ip is loopback, but I could find only one free port by using random numbers in port field. Please tell me how to find a sequence of free ports for tcp.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't guarantee free port numbers.  You will have to scan the ports on the machine looking for free ports anywhere between 1024 and 65535.  If you want to create a client socket you would have to try and connect from each local port you want in sequence, aborting and starting again if you encounter a used port - but of course this could keep happening if another application is trying to grab ports too.  For a server socket, you would have to try and bind to each port in sequence.

For a client socket, do you need to specify the local port?  If not, just allocate the number of connections you want.  For a server socket, I would simply assume that I owned all ports from, say 10000 to 10100.  Although starting a hundred servers probably isn't what you want to do.

With any networking in Java, rather than using the Java .net package, rather use [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) which is much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This might shed some light;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a range of port numbers *at the client?* You can get a free *listening* port via new ServerSocket(0) and interrogating the local port. But there's no good reason why you should need a range of client port numbers (other than over-enthusiastic outbound firewall rules, which netadmins sometimes specify without realizing there is no API to use them).