# Discover available port for derby

Tags: java, sockets, port, derby

This question is almost similar to this previous question [Sockets: Discover port availability using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java). But somehow its not working properly when I check the derby listening port.

```
public static boolean isPortavailable(int port){
    ServerSocket ss = null;
    DatagramSocket ds = null;
    try{
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        ss.setReuseAddress(true);
        ds = new DatagramSocket(port);
        ds.setReuseAddress(true);
        return true;
    }
    catch(IOException e){
    }
    finally{
        if(ss != null){
        try{
            ss.close();
            ds.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            /* should not be thrown */
        }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is my main method

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Derby:"+isPortAvailable(1527));
    System.out.println("Jetty:"+isPortAvailable(7080));
    System.out.println("Tomcat:"+isPortAvailable(8084));
}
```

I started services with the port for derby 1527, jetty 7080 and tomcat 8084. when I run this main method it gives the following result

```
Derby:true
Jetty:false
Tomcat:false
```

I am unable to find why Its giving wrong answer for derby, can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Calling setReuseAddress() after you've already bound the socket to a port accomplishes precisely nothing, and calling it at all in a program of this nature is completely pointless.

Comment: @EJP : that code was from apache project http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/camel/trunk/components/camel-test/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/test/AvailablePortFinder.java?view=markup#l130 I don't have much idea.

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13826145/2546579) for this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/434718/2546579) by