# How to wait till a TCP port is really (natively) closed in Java?

Tags: java, linux, sockets, tcp, apache-zookeeper

### Why am I asking it?

You can skip the story if you want. Still, some might be interested.

I have an embedded ZooKeeper server in Java. In the unit tests, I assign ports to the test servers dynamically. Before assigning the port I check if it is unused by opening up a `ServerSocket`, then closing it.

It happens from time to time, that in the unit tests I get `BindException` when I start up my server *(it cannot be that I assign the same port to two servers since I use File locks as well for mutual exclusion)*. It turned out that the reason is, that for the port check I open up the port, then I close it and it waits for a while in operating system level till the port can be reopened.

There is however an option ([StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/StandardSocketOptions.html#SO_REUSEADDR)) which can tell for the Java socket, that an old socket in TIMED_WAIT state can be reused. After checking the ZooKeeper code it is actually set to true (see [org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure(InetSocketAddress, int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.6/org/apache/zookeeper/server/NIOServerCnxnFactory.java#NIOServerCnxnFactory.configure%28java.net.InetSocketAddress%2Cint%29)):

```
@Override
public void configure(InetSocketAddress addr, int maxcc) throws IOException {
    configureSaslLogin();

    thread = new Thread(this, "NIOServerCxn.Factory:" + addr);
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    maxClientCnxns = maxcc;
    this.ss = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    ss.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
    LOG.info("binding to port " + addr);
    ss.socket().bind(addr);
    ss.configureBlocking(false);
    ss.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
}
```

My [test](http://pastebin.com/Hhyfiz3Y) however prooves that it does not work. I get BindException (under Linux JDK 1.7.0_60).

After checking the ServerSocketChannel implementation (JDK 1.7.0_60) I realized, that this NEVER works under linux. See `sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.setOption(SocketOption<T>, T)`:

```
public <T> ServerSocketChannel setOption(SocketOption<T> paramSocketOption, T paramT) throws IOException
{
    if (paramSocketOption == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (!(supportedOptions().contains(paramSocketOption)))
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("'" + paramSocketOption + "' not supported");
    synchronized (this.stateLock) {
        if (!(isOpen()))
            throw new ClosedChannelException();
        if ((paramSocketOption == StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR) && (Net.useExclusiveBind()))
        {
            this.isReuseAddress = ((Boolean)paramT).booleanValue();
        }
        else {
            Net.setSocketOption(this.fd, Net.UNSPEC, paramSocketOption, paramT);
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `Net.useExclusiveBind()` will never give back true under linux, if you check its source [in the hopefully similar OpenJDK](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/mono-sources/monodevelop/monodevelop-5.9.0.431.tar.gz/monodevelop-5.9/external/ikvm/openjdk/sun/nio/ch/Net.java) it depends on `Net.isExclusiveBindAvailable()`, which is -1 under Linux.

### Do you have a workaround?

Is there a way in Java to wait till a port is really natively closed apart from opening up a `ServerSocket` without SO_REUSEADDR and checking if I get `BindException`? Of course, that is not a solution since then I have to close that ServerSocket again.
Why is there nothing in Java like closing a socket in blocking mode, which would return only when the socket is really on the operating system level closed?

Comment: This question might be of interest to you, in particular TwentyMiles' answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13826145/424903

Comment: Surprised - simply opening and closing a socket puts it in TIME_WAIT state. that is rather strange! Or do you `open`, `bind`, `listen` and `accept` and then `close`? In your particular case I don't think `SO_REUSEADDR` isn't bad per se. As it's unlikely there's any stray unacked data that's going to be lingering around.

Comment: @gabhijit: Take a look at the test code. Yes, there is an accept as well.

Comment: @Gimby : excellent idea. I could simply use a client socket for port testing. Thanks.

Comment: If you can control - client socket - there's indeed no problem (but client socket would then go in TIME_WAIT state). In general TIME_WAIT state isn't a very big problem and in your case it definitely isn't. Also SO_EXCLUSIVEREUSE is a windows only behavior and hence not portable and not expected to work in Linux. (after a quick look at documentation).

Comment: Your test calls `ss.setReuseAddress(false);`, so that would naturally fail (**ALL** sockets have to call `setReuseAddress(true);`, not just one of them.. Tough the code from `sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.setOption` you quote still calls `Net.setSocketOption(this.fd, Net.UNSPEC, paramSocketOption, paramT);`, which should properly set SO_REUSEADDR - you don't need Net.useExclusiveBind() to return true. Your unit test need to call `ss.setReuseAddress(true);`, and you certainly should close the socket you've accepted.

Comment: Get rid of the port-testing part altogether. Just do the real open that you need, of the ServerSocket that you actually plan to use, and deal with the BindException at that point. What you're engaged in at the moment is trying to foretell the future.

Comment: @nos : The ss.setReuseAddress(false) at the top of my test class is actually not interesting. If you set it to true, the error will still come as far as I think. Give it a try. The real point above is that you have no chance to have SO_REUSEADDR under linux for a ServerSocketChannelImpl instance.

Comment: @EJP : it is not that easy to deal with it if the whole thing should "reserve" ports for JMX, HTTP and other ports of several parallel running ServiceMix instances. I do not have control over the code of ServiceMix, I just configure the instances with PAX Exam. I think waiting till a socket is natively closed is really a missing feature in Java.

Comment: @GáborLipták  ss.setReuseAddress(false)  will cause you Zookeeper server to not be able to bind to that port, so I would presume that is quite interesting.  I am also unsure why you think that you cannot have SO_REUSEADDR under linux for a ServerSocketChannelImpl. The code you quote calls Net.setSocketOption(this.fd, Net.UNSPEC, paramSocketOption, paramT);, which ends up with a native setsockopt() call - which is all you need to enable SO_REUSEADDR on linux. (The Net.isExclusiveBindAvailable() is derived from the  sun.net.useExclusiveBind system property, and is relevant only on Windows )

Comment: @nos: I debugged it and it never comes to the line "this.isReuseAddress = ((Boolean)paramT).booleanValue();" on my linux with my JDK version.

Comment: @nos: like I said: ss.setReuseAddress(false)  in the test has nothing to do with ZooKeeper. Zookeeper sets reuseaddress to true (and this has no effect under Linux). The ss.setReuseAddress(false) in the test is not interesting.

Comment: @GáborLipták  That is 100% correct, it should not go to this.isReuseAddress = ((Boolean)paramT).booleanValue(), that is a Windows only codepath. The else clause handles it for linux. And it HAS something to do with Zookeeper, your server socket and the one zookeeper creates uses the same port. As I mentioned, ALL sockets bound to the same port MUST have enabled SO_REUSEADDR  for it to have any effect.

Comment: Your test does not prove any such thing as you are claiming here. It would make more sense, and *work,* that being exactly and only what the API is *for,* if it really did what you state in your question , which is to (a) call `setReuseAddtess(true)` and (b) not do anything at all with `Socket` or `connect()` or `accwot()`, all of which is creating a *second* socket bound to the same port. It is needless and pointless. Voting to close as 'cannot reproduce'.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid your analysis of the `sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.setOption(SocketOption<T>, T)` implementation is not correct.

The "exclusive bind" stuff is used on Windows only, and not relevant for other platforms. You can check this in the [sources of the sun.nio.ch.Net class](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~michaelm/8036979/jdk/01/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/Net.java.html). Specifically, see the comments for `isExclusiveBindAvailable()`.

When exclusive binding is not available, `ServerSocketChannelImpl.setOption` just calls `Net.setSocketOption` which at the end will end up calling the native `setsockopt` function.

BTW the server-side socket might not be in TIME_WAIT state, but also in FIN_WAIT_1 or FIN_WAIT_2 (waiting for the client side to acknowledge the close). This [in-depth description of the TCP state machine](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html) may be helpful.