# How would I choose in java that which port is free to use for ServerSocket or Socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm working on java. How would I check that a port is free to use for a `ServerSocket`? 
Moreover when a Socket is returned by the `accept()` function is it given a port and IP address by default or I would have to specify that too?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java) might help.

Comment: Note you should limit the ports you choose from to the [dynamic / private port range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic.2C_private_or_ephemeral_ports), so 49152–65535.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use Try catch to find a free port**

```
private static int port=9000;
public static int detectPort(int prt)
{
try{
//connect to port
}
catch(Exception e)
{
return detectPort(prt+1);
}
return prt;
}

// Write detectPort(port); inside main
```

Comment: `detectPort(prt++);` will result in an infinite loop, right? Using `prt+1` would be better, I think.

Comment: I did a mistake .. thnx fr letting me know

Comment: Recursion risks a stack overflow here, simpler to just use a loop.  You shouldn't be grabbing any ports lower than 49152, as well.

Comment: Complete waste of time and space. Specifying zero will give you a free port without any retrying at all.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `java.net.ServerSocket` constructor with port `0` which tells `ServerSocket` to find a free port.

[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int)):

> port - the port number, or 0 to use a port number that is
>   automatically allocated.

Example:

```
int port = -1;
try {
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0);
    // here's your free port
    port = socket.getLocalPort();
    socket.close();
} 
catch (IOException ioe) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have released a tiny library for doing just that with tests in mind.
Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>me.alexpanov</groupId>
    <artifactId>free-port-finder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Once installed, free port numbers can be obtained via:

```
int port = FreePortFinder.findFreeLocalPort();
```

Answer (score 1):

We can refer to how Spring's [SocketUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/SocketUtils.java) works.

The key idea is to generate a random port, check whether it's available, and repeat until an available port is found.

```
private enum SocketType {

    TCP {
        @Override
        protected boolean isPortAvailable(int port) {
            try {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = ServerSocketFactory.getDefault().createServerSocket(
                        port, 1, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
                serverSocket.close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    },

    UDP {
        @Override
        protected boolean isPortAvailable(int port) {
            try {
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port, InetAddress.getByName("localhost"));
                socket.close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

};

Comment: Nice race condition if another process on the system does the same.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I check that a port is free to use for a ServerSocket?

You wouldn't. You would specify port 0, which causes the system to give you a free port.

> Moreover when a Socket is returned by the accept() function is it given a port and IP address by default

Yes. It is given the IP address that the peer connected to, and the same port as the listening socket.

> or I would have to specify that too?

No.