# Java Multithreading,Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I am trying to implement a Thread which pings LAN connections continously. I would like to do that by creating new `Socket` for each IP, while handling exceptions if it fails to connect. However, the execution of the sequence **time outs** at creating the socket (i signed it with a comment in the code).

**How could i solve this Problem?**

```
class Ping implements Runnable
{

    private int actPort = 1024; 

    public void run()
    {           
        Socket s;
        int[] ip = {192,168,0,0};

        while(true){

            try {

                for(int i = 0;i<256;i++)
                {
                    ip[2] = i;

                    for(int j = 0;j<256;j++)
                    {

                        ip[3] = j;
                        String address = ip[0]+"."+ip[1]+"."+ip[2]+"."+ip[3];
                        s = new Socket(address,actPort); // EXECUTION STOPS
                        System.out.println(address);                            
                    }
                }                   

            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: does it time out eventually?

Comment: Nope, sorry i edited the question.

Comment: so why do you think it would not time out, if the ip address does not exist?

Comment: The timeout could be as high as three minutes.  This could be a long process to hit 65536 IP addresses. You could use multiple threads however an asynchronous connection with your own timeout might be more practical.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `Socket`, which is a TCP/IP Stream and creates statefull connection between you (client) and given `IP`, `PORT`.
I assume, this program stop while creating first `Socket`.

If you look at the API of `Socket` class:

```
 * If UDP socket is used, TCP/IP related socket options will not apply.
 *
 * @param      host     the IP address.
 * @param      port      the port number.
 * @param      stream    if {@code true}, create a stream socket;
 *                       otherwise, create a datagram socket.
@Deprecated
public Socket(InetAddress host, int port, boolean stream) throws IOException {
    this(host != null ? new InetSocketAddress(host, port) : null,
         new InetSocketAddress(0), stream);
}
```

This is `@Deprecated` version of creating UDP Socket, but what you REALLY need is `DatagramPacket` from `java.net`, which creates stateless connection, and may be timed out if packet didn't come to the end.

Look here for some example code of writing `DatagramPacket`:

https://github.com/awadalaa/Socket-Programming-Java/blob/master/UDP-Pinger/PingClient.java

Answer (score 1):

Your are trying to do both an ip scanner( loop on all 192.168) and a port scanner. So you could search solutions for both:
[java code to ping an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506321/java-code-to-ping-an-ip-address) 
[Sockets: Discover port availability using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java)

For the multithreading part, it makes 65536 value to test, it would make too many Threads, so you can use a ThreadPool with executors, and cancel it if it takes too long.

see the method to use (i let you do the algorithm

```
tp = Executors.newWorkStealingPool(512); // to create up to 512 Threads
//todo the creation loop...
future = tp.submit(()->{/* your port scan */ return true;});
//todo the waiting processing
future.cancel(true);// to cancel your future
```