# Java check if port is open and reachable for other computers

Tags: java, ip, port

Is it even possible to check if port is open and reachable to others?

Right now I'm using to check if my listener is reachable by using [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org) by simply entering port number.

What I want to know is it possible to make my application to detect if port is reachable to others, not using local ip.

Comment: does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, you can use a library like NETTY or you can check previously answered topic 
[Sockets: Discover port availability using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java)

Comment: This should be a duplication not an answer tbh :)

Comment: Sorry not sure how to mark it as a duplicate, i will look up how for next time.

Comment: No problem. You simply click the "flag" button under the question and everything from there should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Not sure if this works the same way as canyouseeme.org. It does check if port is available, this is ok I need this. But does it check is port reachable for others as well ? other computers etc.

Comment: @Gaxt honestly, I would advice you to use a library like netty, it has exactly what you want to do.