# Socket throws an exception, although the port is free

Tags: java, scala, sockets

I have the method, that should return true, if the socket port is free.

The implementation of the method:

```
  private def isPortFree(host: String, port: Int): Boolean = {
    import java.net.Socket
    try {
      // Socket try to open a REMOTE port
      new Socket(host, port).close()
      true
    } catch {
      case _: Exception => false
    }
  }
```

When the object gets initialized, then it throws an exception:

```
Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

although the port is available. The host is "0.0.0.0".

[image]

I am trying to validate, if the given port is free or not.

Comment: Did you mean `ServerSocket`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sockets: Discover port availability using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434718/sockets-discover-port-availability-using-java)

Comment: I think you should first open socket, like in try-with-resiurces. See link upper

Comment: Why not show the code that is throwing the "Connection Refused" exception? It's hard to imagine what you're doing because you just opened and immediately closed the connection, so there is no connection anymore to be "refused".

Comment: If you create a socket, you are connecting to something. As you mention that the port is free, then there is nothing to connect to. Hence the 'connection refused' error.